# Problema con subprocess | Python

Tags: python

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.run(
    ['mkdir', 'hola'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True
)

print(process.stderr)
print(process.stdout)
```

No crea la carpeta "hola", pero lo raro es que el proceso da el siguiente error:

```
b"mkdir: falta un operando\nPruebe 'mkdir --help' para m\xc3\xa1s informaci\xc3\xb3n.\n" # print(process.stderr)
```

Es como que le pasara como primer parámetro `['mkdir']` en ves de `['mkdir', 'hola']`, pero no lo se.

También intente con lo siguiente: `['cp', 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt']` y sucedió algo parecido:

```
b"cp: falta un fichero como operando\nPruebe 'cp --help' para m\xc3\xa1s informaci\xc3\xb3n.\n"
```

¿Que sucede? (hace unos días, funcionaba bien... y no tengo ni la menor idea del porque no funciona ahora)

Comment: Si sacas `shell=True`, funciona. `mkdir` es un comando externo; lo puedes ejecutar directamente, sin necesidad del shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando intentas ejecutar un comando con el argumento `shell=True`, lo que haces es ejecutar el interprete de comandos pasando la lista de argumentos. ¿Cual interprete de comandos? Depende de tu sistema operativo, de como lo tengas configurado; en Linux al menos hay un montón de shells a elegir.

En Linux, el shell lo determina la variable de ambiente `$SHELL`. En mi PC, con Linux Mint, `$SHELL` apunta a `/bin/bash`.

Ahora, `bash` se llama con este formato:

```
NAME
       bash - GNU Bourne-Again SHell

SYNOPSIS
       bash [options] [command_string | file]
```

que nos dice que espera una invocación pasando opcionalmente una **cadena** que contiene el comando a ejecutar. En este caso, también tengo que usar la opción `-c` para indicar que a continuación viene una cadena con el comando. Por tanto, si quiere crear un directorio, debo escribir en la línea de comandos:

```
bash -c "mkdir hola"
```

Rebuscado, pero ilustra el punto.

**Alternativa `shell=True`**

Sólo necesitas invocar el comando con `shell=True` si quieres que el shell ejecute algunas acciones propias, como expandir variables de ambientes o convertir especificaciones ambiguas de archivos (como `*.lst`) en una lista explicita.

En este caso, debes pasar una sola cadena con el comando completo: `['mkdir hola']`

**Alternativa `shell=False`**

En tu caso, no necesitas nada de eso. Puedes decir `shell=False`, u omitir el parámetro e ejecutar `run` pasando un arreglo con cada elemento por separado: `['mkdir', 'hola']`

**Ejemplo**

Quiero listar todos los `.txt` en mi directorio.

Puedo hacerlo con `ls *.txt`, pero eso requiere expandir `*.txt`, que es tarea del shell:

```
process = subprocess.run(['ls *.txt'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
```

produce:

```
b'activos.txt\narchivo.txt\ncombo_solucion.txt\ncombos.txt\ncon.txt\ncooldown.txt\ndatos.txt\nhistorico.txt\nmbox-short.txt\nnewfile-combos.txt\nnif.txt\nsentimientos.txt\nTweets.txt\n'
```

¿Que paso si lo hago con `shell=False`

```
process = subprocess.run(['ls', '*.txt'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = False)
```

produce:

```
b"ls: cannot access '*.txt': No such file or directory\n"
b''
```

porque el program `ls` recibio como argumento `*.txt` y ese es un archivo que no existe. Recuerda que en Linux es el shell quien expande `*.txt` antes de ejecutar el programa.

Moraleja: omite `shell=True`